# Notepad++ Change color of next highlighted text

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

When highlighting certain text, Notepad++ can highlight other matching text. I want to change background color of the other matching text (in the attached shot, I want to change the gray color), does anyone know?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Such an option doesn't exist. The only customization possible is "Smart HighLighting":

[image]

There is a slight difference because the selected text has also the selection indication,
which makes it a bit darker.

If the difference is too slight to see, you may perhaps change the highlight color
to make it a lighter color. The difference might then be more noticeable.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. the problem is if you see in my shot, the theme that I chose is highlighting the next matching with different color which is dimming the underlying word.. so I wished if I can change this gray color

Comment: You may have to modify the theme or choose another. The colors do not combine well.